# How to remove lines which contain certain word/charater twice in notepad+

Tags: regex

i want to know if we can remove all the lines in notepad+ that contain specfic letter or word twice in one single line.

for my problem i have a big text file and i want to remove all lines that contain email address twice.. thou the email ID is not the same but i simply just dont want that line,
so i thou i can remove all notepad lines that contain @ sign twice... but unforunatly i dont know how to do that.
so can anyone please tell me with the regex of this process and if there are any better alternatives please also mention that

thanks

Comment: sln i meant any letter twice in a line.. no matter what is the pattern... either @@ or @blah blah @

Comment: casimir.. thou= though

Comment: It wasn't really a question, but an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The below regex would match all the lines which has two `@` symbols. Just replace the matched strings with an empty string will delete that corresponding line.

```
^.*?@.*?@.*\n?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vQ1vM3/2)

Comment: Thanks ALOTTTTT Avinash Raj..
did exactly as i needed

Comment: btw bro tell me what to change in this regex to select lines with 3 @s?

Comment: add an extra `.*?@` symbol like `^.*?@.*?@.*?@.*(?:\n|$)`

Comment: You can change `(?:\n|$)` to `\n?`

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution could be replacing

```
.*(.).*(\1).*
```

with `\n`

Comment: or replacing with null character

Comment: replace (.) with any character(s) you want